# jQuery tmpl: How do I render Html?

Tags: jquery, html, encoding, jquery-templates

Okay, I'm in a sitiuation with jQuery, the tmpl-plugin and this:

```
${$value.Text}
```

This is okay and works fine but as I just found out via [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/):

> Using {{html fieldNameOrExpression}}
>   is equivalent to using
>   ${fieldNameOrExpression}, except that
>   it renders unencoded text into the
>   HTML DOM, whereas ${} encodes values
>   by default.

Okay fine. But I can't get the `{{html}}` tag to work with my `${$value.Text}`.

I tried things like `{{html ${$value.Text}}` or `{html ${$value.Text}}` but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
{{html $value.Text}}
```

Comment: If you're working within Laravel's blade, like I am, you will need to escape out of it. Example: @{{html value}}

Comment: This did not work for me.  The other answer is what worked.

Answer (score 18):

What worked for me was:

```
{{html value.Text}}
```

Comment: This worked fine ex.  {{html GeneralComments}}, thank you