# Decode html string in JQuery Mobile template

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery templates which I populate using an ajax request. However, one of the values returned is encoded HTML. How can I encode it?

I have tried using `${$.mobile.html(Body).text()}` but that didn't work for me.

My code:

```
Domain.Discussion.ListView = Domain.Discussion.ListView || {
    DiscussionPage: (function () {
        var onGetDiscussionSuccess = function (data) {
            $("#discussionsList ul").remove();
            $("#discussionListItem").tmpl(data.DiscussionsResult).appendTo("#discussionsList", function () {
                reloadAndFixPanelContent()
            });
        }

        var onGetDiscussionError = function () {
            console.log("Error occured when retrieving discussions");
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: absolutePath + "Discussions",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: onGetDiscussionSuccess,
            error: onGetDiscussionError
        });
    }())
};
```

Html:

```
<!-- Discussion replies -->
<script id="replies" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="message message-first">
    <div class="message-header">
        <div class="message-header-user">
            <h1>${Author}</h1>
            <h2>Role not set yet</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="message-header-date">${Created}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-content">
        <span>${$.mobile.html(Body).text()}</span>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<!-- /Discussion replies -->
```

Comment: Can you show us your ajax response?

Comment: The ajax call returns, json formatted, a few items. Including an item called `Body` with value (HTML Encoded) `<div class="ExternalClassC23D0863D23B4421A039D700D6AECF79">Hejsan hoppsan!<br><p>​</p></div>`.

Comment: What I don't understand is what do you mean by "encoded HTML"?

Comment: e.g. `<p>Hello, world!</p>` becomes `&lt;p&gt;Hello, world!&lt;/p&gt;` when encoded. 
I found the solution now.

Comment: Ahaaaaaaaaaa, but because you fond an answer we will stop our conversation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and searching I finally found the solution here:
[jQuery tmpl: How do I render Html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618868/jquery-tmpl-how-do-i-render-html)

Using `{{html Body}}` in my template worked like a charm.